# TypeScript warning for connected component with own props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have two components (smart and dumb) as follows:

```
// Container component file...

interface OwnProps {
  id: Id;
}

function mapStateToProps(state: State, ownProps: OwnProps) {
    return { isActive: ... };
}

export const Container: any = connect(mapStateToProps, null)(DumbComponent);

// Dumb component file...

interface DumbComponentProperties {
    isActive: boolean;
}

export class DumbComponent extends React.Component<DumbComponentProperties, {}> {
    ...
}
```

I get a red-squiggly warning under the `DumbComponent` inside `connect`, that:

> Argument of type 'typeof DumbComponent' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'Component OwnProps & { isActive: boolean;
>   }'....>

If I make `id` optional via `id?`, this fixes the error.  This looks like TypeScript thinks `DumbComponent` needs the `OwnProps` type as well because `id` is being passed as a prop to it?  I don't understand why this is the case though, isn't only the property `isActive` being passed to `DumbComponent`?

Comment: Where are the types State and Id defined ?

Comment: They are defined inside the store.  I don't believe that that information is relevant to my problem.

Comment: It's strange because the code actually works for me, if I fill in simple interfaces for those types ..

Comment: Hm.... I'll take a look again but I think I just pretty much copied everything and changed names to anonymize stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your code but it's a good practice to type the function mapStateToProps function, like,

`function mapStateToProps(state: State, ownProps: OwnProps): DumbComponentProperties  {
    return { isActive: ... };
}`